# Change JObject name

Tags: json.net

I have my json :

```
{
     "house":{  
        "Color":"White",
        "Car":"None"
     }
}
```

having

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);
```

How can I change name from "house" to e.g. "bigHouse" using JObject from Newtonsoft?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JObject data = JObject.Parse(json);
data.Add('bigHouse', data.house);
data.house.Remove();
```

Does the trick